# How can I make my program stop reading user input when no input is given?

Tags: c#, parsing

I am trying to make a program that calculates some specific data from numbers given by a user.
In this example, my program counts amount of numbers in range (10,103) that are divisible by 2, and amount of numbers that are in range (15,50) divisible by 3 within numbers given by user.
On this stage, my program gives the results, when 10 numbers are given (as I specified it in the loop). How can I make my program stop reading numbers and give the results when user imputs an empty line no matter if he, entered 5 or 100 numbers before?

Here is my code, as it looks for now:

```
using System;

namespace Program1
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            int input10_103_div_2 = 0;
            int input15_50_div_3 = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine ();
                double xinput = double.Parse (input);

                if (xinput > 10 && xinput <= 103 && (xinput % 2) == 0)
                {
                    input10_103_div_2++;
                }
                if (xinput > 15 && xinput < 50 && (xinput % 3) == 0) 
                {
                    input15_50_div_3++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine ("Amount of numbers in range (10,103) divisible by 2: " + input10_103_div_2);
            Console.WriteLine ("Amount of numbers in range (15,50) divisible by 3: " + input15_50_div_3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to restructure the loop, you can use a `do while` loop:

```
string input;
do{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    //stuff
} while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input));
```

If you just want to be able to break early:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine ();
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
  break;
double xinput = double.Parse (input);
```

Comment: in this scenario he will be doing //stuff against an empty string.  He'll need another if for validation

Comment: @Jonesy Right, that is fine. `Do while` conveys his logic the best and I was shooting for his requirement of "no matter if he entered 5 or 100".

Comment: @Jonesy Which in my opinion is no worse than your answer using two `Console.ReadLine`.

Comment: Yeah I suppose its just personal choice

Comment: If you use a `do while` you have to add another `if statement` after the input to check for an empty string (which completely defeats the purpose of using a `do while` instead of an infinite loop, in my opinion). In this case and without a check for empty, when input is empty, the `do while` will throw a format exception on the next line because it will evaluate `double.Parse ("");`.

Comment: @dhsto That is true but I didn't know the OP would allow 0 numbers to be inputted. "no matter if he entered 5 or 100".  My answer assumes at least 1 number as input.

Comment: @dhsto And like I said, he can add another `if` and then it is *no worse* than using Jonesy's answer.

Comment: @dhsto In your answer, using `for (;;)` does not convey meaning and is bad style in my opinion (and others).

Comment: @AustinHenley the do while needs to be changed to this otherwise you will get a FormatException on `Double.Parse`: `do { input = Console.ReadLine(); if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)) { /* do stuff here */ } } while(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(input));` So you have to check a condition twice before exiting.

Comment: @AustinHenley `for(;;)` is classic syntax for infinite loop. You could also use `while(true) { }`. It means the same thing.

Comment: @dhsto And both are equally bad.

Comment: @AustinHenley Why would you think that?

Answer (score 5):

instead of for, do:

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
while(input != String.Empty)
{
     //do things
     input = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

if you're trying to allow any number of inputs. Or

```
if(input == "")
    break;
```

if you want the for loop

Answer (score 2):

Change your loop to go forever and break out of the loop when the string is empty:

```
for (;;)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine ();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        break;
    }

    // rest of code inside loop goes here
}
```